# Redux update view

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am learning redux with react and I have one question regarding the use of it. Does redux update the view after a database field value has changed? Does the update happen on all the opened windows?

For example I have a table with some invoices. I update the value of one invoice but the view does not update without reloading the page.
After I update the view using callback function the view updates on the current opened window, but not on other opened window in other browser.

I can't attache code because I don't have copyright on it.

Comment: change variable names and then you should be able to post the code

Comment: You are _learning_ redux on production code ??!

Comment: Are you talking about pusher because I don't think there is any way of sharing javascript across tabs

Comment: I think you should read the [Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/). Long story short, we dispatch actions, and any view that subscribes to the action ( via a reducer ) gets updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux is a predictable state container.

Meaning, it is just a store which you can update when something changes. Components which are subscribed to the store, by using [connect](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/31/react-redux-connect-explained/) mapping store state to the props of the component, will be rerendered when there is a change in object.

So if your view has different components which uses same prop from redux store, all components will be rerendered, when the value changes.

> After I update the view using callback function the view updates on
>   the current opened window, but not on other opened window in other
>   browser.

Another browser tab won't be updated. That is a different window altogether with it's own context and DOM elements :) You should use some event based communication like [Socket.io](https://socket.io/) to achieve real time changes in all windows.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanations! It' more clear now! :)